# Why grep with xargs does not read the full path?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I want to extract the name of all the files in /myfolder/data/* created in July of 2014 which contains the word 'stackoverflow'.

I did this:

```
find /myfolder/data/ -type f -name "*" -printf '%a\t%p\r\n' | 
grep -P 'Jul.+\s2014' | 
awk '{print $6}'
```

This works, prints all the files that I want to aply the grep:

```
/myfolder/data/EF50/myfile1
/myfolder/data/EF50/myfile2
```

But if I add the grep:

```
find /myfolder/data/ -type f -name "*" -printf '%a\t%p\r\n' | 
grep -P 'Jul.+\s2014' | 
awk '{print $6}' | 
xargs grep -l 'stackoverflow'
```

It returns the following:

```
: No such file or directoryF50/myfile1
: No such file or directoryF50/myfile2
```

Could you tell me where is the mistake? There is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Side note: you don't need an end-of-line backslash if your line ends on a pipe symbol.

Comment: And surprise: what do you need that `\r` for?  Is that your problem?

Comment: Oh thanks, I did't realiced.

Comment: The clue about `\r` here by the way is that that error message is printed over top of itself (that is the error message shouldn't look exactly like that, try grep on a normal file that doesn't exist and see the difference).

Comment: Note you are not listing `creation time`, but `access time`. Whether or not you can even get `creation time` depends entirely on your file system. Also, you could technically do this without piping by doing some `stat` comparison in an `-exec` block, or just do the `grep` earlier like `find /myfolder/data/ -type f -exec grep -q stackoverflow {} \; -printf '%a\t%p\r\n' | 
grep -P 'Jul.+\s2014'`, though testing the date first is probably faster.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I think the best solution is:
`find /myfolder/data/ -type f -ctime -5 -exec grep -l 'stackoverflow' {} \;` :)